# fix 502 gate way error in react/nginx in aws

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, nginx

i try to run a react application on amazon ec2 instance.when i listen on default port(port:3000) it's running perfectly, but when change the port number from 3000 to 4000 by, it shows 502 gate way error like below.

MY NGINX SETUP:

```
   server {
      listen 80 default_server;
      server_name MY_DOMAIN;

      return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
         }

   server {
       listen 443 ssl default_server;
       server_name MY_DOMAIN;

       ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/MY_DOMAIN/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
       ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/MY_DOMAIN/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
       include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
       ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


       location / {
           proxy_pass 
           http://PRIVATE_IP:4000;
           proxy_http_version 1.1;
           proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
           proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
           proxy_set_header Host $host;
           proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
       }

       location /server {
           proxy_pass 
           http://PRIVATE_IP:5000;
           proxy_http_version 1.1;
           proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
           proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
           proxy_set_header Host $host;
           proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
       } 

}


 GET https://MY_DOMAIN_URL/static/js/6.chunk.js net::ERR_ABORTED 502 (Bad 
 Gateway)
 favicon.ico:1 GET https://MY_DOMAIN_URL/favicon.ico 502 (Bad Gateway)
 manifest.json:1 GET https://MY_DOMAIN_URL/manifest.json 502 (Bad 
 Gateway)
 manifest.json:1 Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error.
```

Comment: What kind of service are you running on port 3000 to host the react-files on the EC2?

Comment: Can the React application be run as just a static web site? If so, deploying your static content to an S3 bucket with CloudFront can be a much cheaper and more maintainable solution. This seems to be a decent walkthrough: https://medium.com/ovrsea/deploy-automatically-a-react-app-on-amazon-s3-iam-within-minutes-da6cb0096d55